# Represent computer function logic as Math function

Tags: functions

Say I have a simple C function that returns a "result" for a number, based on doing some calculations with pre-defined ranges. How can I represent this function in a "mathematical" form with all its related symbols etc.

```
const int lowEndExample1 = 30;
const int highEndExample1 = 33;
const int lowEndExample2 = 60;
const int highEndExample2 = 63;

int GetResult(int num)
{
  int rc = 0;

  if (num >= lowEndExample1 && num <= highEndExample1)
   rc += 10;

  if (num >= lowEndExample2 && num <= highEndExample2)
   rc += 20;

  return rc;
}
```

Comment: As a piecewise function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise

Answer (score 1):

$$
\operatorname{GetResult}(x)=\begin{cases}10&\text{if }30\le x\le 33,\\
20&\text{if }60\le x\le 63,\\
0&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}
$$
Note that special care would have to be taken if $30\le x\le 33$ and $60\le x\le 63$ were not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your code, you set `rc = 0` at the top of the function. So you have three possible return values: 0, 10, 20. Hence, your increment of `rc` is unnecessary, or perhaps this is not what you intended.

$$r_c = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 10, & \textrm{if } a \le \textrm{num} \le b, \\
20, & \textrm{if } c \le \textrm{num} \le d, \\
0, & \textrm{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.$$
Set $a = 30$, $b = 33$, $c = 60$, $d = 63$ to correspond to your low end/high end values.